# Invalid Read of size 8 and other things

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind

I am new to C and I seem to be having so issues implementing a linked list. The List works, what doesn't work is the memory management. I am not the greatest at it but I seem to be doing some things wrong.

I a receiving an invalid read of size 8 from valgrind. The Exact error is as follows:

```
==2155== Invalid read of size 8
==2155==    at 0x401271: DestroyLinkedList (in /home/btm7984/hw3/TestList)
==2155==    by 0x400EFE: main (TestList.c:92)
==2155==  Address 0x8788218 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==2155==    at 0x4C2A82E: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-lin ux.so)
==2155==    by 0x401202: RemoveFromBackOfLinkedList (in /home/btm7984/hw3/TestLis t)
==2155==    by 0x400EB3: main (TestList.c:87)
==2155==
==2155== Invalid read of size 8
==2155==    at 0x401242: DestroyLinkedList (in /home/btm7984/hw3/TestList)
==2155==    by 0x400EFE: main (TestList.c:92)
==2155==  Address 0x8788218 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==2155==    at 0x4C2A82E: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-lin ux.so)
==2155==    by 0x401202: RemoveFromBackOfLinkedList (in /home/btm7984/hw3/TestLis t)
==2155==    by 0x400EB3: main (TestList.c:87)
==2155==
==2155== Invalid read of size 8
==2155==    at 0x40124E: DestroyLinkedList (in /home/btm7984/hw3/TestList)
==2155==    by 0x400EFE: main (TestList.c:92)
==2155==  Address 0x8788210 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==2155==    at 0x4C2A82E: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-lin ux.so)
==2155==    by 0x401202: RemoveFromBackOfLinkedList (in /home/btm7984/hw3/TestLis t)
==2155==    by 0x400EB3: main (TestList.c:87)
==2155==
==2155== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==2155==    at 0x4C2A82E: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-lin ux.so)
==2155==    by 0x401258: DestroyLinkedList (in /home/btm7984/hw3/TestList)
==2155==    by 0x400EFE: main (TestList.c:92)
==2155==  Address 0x8788160 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 104 free'd
==2155==    at 0x4C2A82E: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-lin ux.so)
==2155==    by 0x400EE0: main (TestList.c:89)
==2155==
==2155== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==2155==    at 0x4C2A82E: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-lin ux.so)
==2155==    by 0x401264: DestroyLinkedList (in /home/btm7984/hw3/TestList)
==2155==    by 0x400EFE: main (TestList.c:92)
==2155==  Address 0x8788210 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==2155==    at 0x4C2A82E: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-lin ux.so)
==2155==    by 0x401202: RemoveFromBackOfLinkedList (in /home/btm7984/hw3/TestLis t)
==2155==    by 0x400EB3: main (TestList.c:87)
==2155==
==2155== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==2155==    at 0x4C2A82E: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-lin ux.so)
==2155==    by 0x400F1C: main (TestList.c:94)
==2155==  Address 0x8787dd0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==2155==    at 0x4C2A82E: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-lin ux.so)
==2155==    by 0x401264: DestroyLinkedList (in /home/btm7984/hw3/TestList)
==2155==    by 0x400EFE: main (TestList.c:92)
==2155==
==2155== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==2155==    at 0x4C2A82E: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-lin ux.so)
==2155==    by 0x400F2B: main (TestList.c:95)
==2155==  Address 0x8787dd0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==2155==    at 0x4C2A82E: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-lin ux.so)
==2155==    by 0x401264: DestroyLinkedList (in /home/btm7984/hw3/TestList)
==2155==    by 0x400EFE: main (TestList.c:92)
==2155==
==2155==
==2155== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2155==     in use at exit: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==2155==   total heap usage: 413,183 allocs, 413,188 frees, 26,444,136 bytes allo cated
==2155==
==2155== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2155==    definitely lost: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==2155==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2155==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2155==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2155==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2155== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==2155==
==2155== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2155== ERROR SUMMARY: 13 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

This is comming from the following code:

```
   FILE *fp;
   char tmpString[100];
   LinkedLists *ListPtr = malloc(sizeof(LinkedLists));
   ElementStructs *DataPtr;
   LinkedListNodes* curr = malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNodes));
   int counter = 0;
   int Done = 0;
   if (argc ==2){
   InitLinkedList(ListPtr);
   fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   if (!fp){
     fprintf(stderr,"%s Cannot open file %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
     exit(1);
   }
   do{
     fscanf(fp,"%s",tmpString);
     if (!feof(fp)) {
       DataPtr = malloc(sizeof(ElementStructs));
       strcpy(DataPtr->str,tmpString);
       DataPtr->index=counter;
       AddToBackOfLinkedList(ListPtr, DataPtr);
       counter++;
       Done = 1;
     } else {
       Done = 0;
     }
   }while (Done);

   printf("The first 6 elements of the LinkedList:\n");
   curr = ListPtr->FrontPtr;
   printf("Element %d is %s\n",curr->ElementPtr->index,curr->ElementPtr->str);
   curr = curr->Next;
   printf("Element %d is %s\n",curr->ElementPtr->index,curr->ElementPtr->str);
   curr = curr->Next;
   printf("Element %d is %s\n",curr->ElementPtr->index,curr->ElementPtr->str);
   curr = curr->Next;
   printf("Element %d is %s\n",curr->ElementPtr->index,curr->ElementPtr->str);
   curr = curr->Next;
   printf("Element %d is %s\n",curr->ElementPtr->index,curr->ElementPtr->str);
   curr = curr->Next;
   printf("Element %d is %s\n\n",curr->ElementPtr->index,curr->ElementPtr->str);


   fclose(fp);
   DestroyLinkedList(ListPtr);
   free(ListPtr);
   free(curr);
   free(curr);
   exit(0);
   return 0;
   } else {
     fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s <inputfile>", argv[0]);
     return 2;
   }
```

In a separate Module I have some of these functions defined Noteably, DestroyLinkedLists:

```
void DestroyLinkedList(LinkedLists *ListPtr){
   LinkedListNodes* temp = ListPtr->FrontPtr;
   LinkedListNodes* nextTemp = ListPtr->FrontPtr;
   for (;temp->Next!=NULL;){
     nextTemp = temp->Next;
     free (temp->ElementPtr);
     free (temp);
     temp = nextTemp;
   }ListPtr->NumElements=0;
   ListPtr->FrontPtr=NULL;
   ListPtr->BackPtr=NULL;
}
```

Any help in figuring out these memory errors would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For one thing, calling `free(curr)` twice in a row can't possibly be right.

Comment: *"Address 0x8788218 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd"* What more do you want me to tell you? Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: I know. But I do not know what that line means. Also, that free(curr) was a typo, but the errors still persist

Comment: It doesn't make sense to call `free(curr)` after calling `DestroyLinkedList(ListPtr)`, since the latter will free all elements of the linked-list, of which `curr` is one. Also, you initialize `curr` to `malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNodes))`, but then the very next thing you do with `curr` is change it to point somewhere else, which completely discards that originally-allocated memory. So overall, I'd say the problem is that you're just not being very careful with your pointers.

Comment: Thank you. I am mostly a Java Programer. I am quite bad at memory as a result

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems I found your Code...

**Problem no 1: Destroy Function should be like this,**

```
void DestroyLinkedList(LinkedLists *ListPtr)
{
        while(ListPtr->FrontPtr != NULL)
        {
                LinkedListNodes *removedNode = ListPtr->FrontPtr;
                ListPtr->FrontPtr = ListPtr->FrontPtr->Next;

                /* Deallocate element in node */
                free(removedNode->ElementPtr);

                /* Deallocate node */
                free(removedNode);
        }
        free(ListPtr);
}
```

Code after calling Destroy Function in `main`,

```
...
fclose(fp);
DestroyLinkedList(ListPtr);
//free(ListPtr); //remove these 3 lines
//free(curr);
//free(curr);
...
```

**Problem no 2: Why are you `malloc` `curr`, you are using it for traversing purpose,**

```
ElementStructs *DataPtr;
//LinkedListNodes* curr = malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNodes)); //remove malloc this line and add following line,
LinkedListNodes* curr;
int counter = 0;
```

Can you please paste the structure of `ElementStructs`..?

Like Link would be helpful :)

[Memory Leaks in C Linked List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069536/memory-leaks-in-c-linked-list/14069797#14069797)